Converting generic types implicitly
I have a generic Result class
I want to write an implicit operator function so I can cast Result-T  to Result-V but I could not figure out how to do it.
public class Result<T>
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public T? Data { get; set; }
    
    private ServiceResult(bool isSuccess, T? data, List<string> messages)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
        Data = data;
        Messages = messages;
    }

    public static ServiceResult<T> Success(T data) => new(true, data, "");

    public static implicit operator Result<T>(Result<V> v) 
    {
        if(v.Data !=null){
            throw new Exception("Cannot convert ServiceResult<V> to ServiceResult<T> when V is not null");
        }
        return new ServiceResult<T>
        {
            IsSuccess = v.IsSuccess,
            Messages = v.Messages,
            Data = default(T)
        };
    }

}

I want to use it in a similar case
public Result<string> RandomFunction(){
    ...
    Result<int> countResult = GetCount();
    if (!countResult.IsSuccess)
    {
         return countResult;
    }  
    ...    
}



If changing the type can go wrong (as in your case when Data is null), you should not use implicit casting. Use explicit casting instead.

That's not the typical Result class and some of the question's issues are caused by this. Eg, what if someone sets all properties to unexpected values? It would be better if you used a public record Result<T>(T? Value,string? Message){ public bool IsSuccess=>Value!=null;} and used pattern matching to ensure success and error values are handled.

@PanagiotisKanavos I have a private constructor, added to code

You could write your class as
public class Result<T>(bool isSuccess, List<string> messages, T? data)
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set;} = isSuccess;
    public List<string> Messages { get; set;} = messages;
    public T? Data { get; set;} = data;
    public static implicit operator Result<T>(List<string> messages) => new(false, messages, default);
}

allowing you to write
public Result<string> RandomFunction(){
    ...
    Result<int> countResult = GetCount();
    if (!countResult.IsSuccess)
    {
         return countResult.Messages;
    }  
    ...    
}

Assuming messages and isSuccess is mutably exclusive. Note that the example is using the latest c# features for compactness. I would also seriously consider making the class immutable. You might also want to add some more checks to prevent mistakes.

For the compiler, Result<T> and Result<V> are the same type, while C# does not allow user defined conversions to be defined for the same type. You can either change the parameter type or the return type to a constructed type:
public static implicit operator Result<T>(Result<int> v) 
public static implicit operator Result<string>(Result<T> v) 

or use a generic method:
public Result<T> Cast<V>(Result<V> v)

